# Reusing Animations for another character?

Tags: animation, rigging

Are you able to reuse an animation on a certain rig for one character to another identical rig corresponding to a different character/model? I want to know because I want to practice animating a lower value model until I am ready to work on my characters. Then, I want to reuse those animations on the characters' rigs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you have to make sure that the objects (rigs) are identical.

## The Action Editor

Either open up a *Dope Sheet* window or change to the *Animation Screen layout*.

[image]

Change to the *Action Editor* in the dropdown menu where it likely currently says *Dope Sheet*.

[image] --> [image]

If you select the rig that you already have animated, it will probably display something like *ArmatureAction* where it says *+ New* in the above screenshot. If you select the unanimated armature, you can select *ArmatureAction* from the dropdown menu to the left of *+ New*.

*The Process:*

[image]

This can work for any number and any type of object. For example, if I have a cube keyframed for *X-Location* and *X-Rotation*, I can use the same method to copy its movements to a nearby cone and cylinder.

*Extended uses:*

[image]

The demo .blend:

[image]

Hope this helps; feel free to ask questions!

Comment: @MoonLight If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark in the upper left-hand corner. It would help me greatly! Thank you.

Comment: I just saw this. Wish I've would've saw it sooner, since I haven't been on for a while. Thanks :)

Comment: @MoonLight No problem :)