# I want to Integrate Animations with my friend

Tags: animation, actions

Me and my friend want to work with the same rig(skeleton), integrating our own animations that were made in the same rig(skeleton) but in different workspaces. For example, my friend will animate the walk of the rig and I will animate the crouch of the rig.

How do we incorporate those animations together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have defined your rig, you can both save your animations as [actions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/actions.html) that can be re-used. You can the share the files back with each other and use the append option in the file menu to combine them into one scene if you need.

Actions are blender's way of storing animation sequences for re-use and combining with others, and if you intend to export this to another program like a game engine, are also very useful for managing this.

You may also find this related question helpful: [Reusing Animations for another character?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82748/reusing-animations-for-another-character?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, we are new to Blender, so this will be a great help for us.